# How to adjust the indentation in longtable?

Tags: longtable, indentation

I want to adjust the indentation of my table in the following longtable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2mm}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \small
    \begin{longtable}{|@{\hspace*{\leftmargin}}p{2cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|}
        \caption{Summary of decomposition techniques executed on the EEG signals and their significant results}\label{tab:summary}\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Ordering techniques} &  \textbf{Real-world applications}    &   \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Limitations} \\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{4}{c}%
        {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Ordering techniques} &  \textbf{Real-world applications}    &   \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Limitations} \\
        \hline
        \endhead
        \hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
        \endfoot
        \hline
        \endlastfoot
    \end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```

that produces the following table:

[image]

How can I adjust the indentation in the table (red square)?

Comment: The indentation is caused by the use of `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}`. Depending on the expected indentation you want to achieve, you could replace `18pt` with a value that suits your needs or entirely remove the whole line for a default white space of `6pt`. The horizontal white space in the first column is cuased by `@{\hspace*{\leftmargin}}`. Is this intentional? If not, what was this piece of code supposed to do?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @leandriis. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments